# Rails 3.1 limit user created objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, limit

I would like to limit the number of model Objects a user can create.  I've tried the below but it is not working.  I understand some changes have happened in rails 3.1 and not sure how to accomplish this now.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things, :limit => 5, :dependent => :destroy # This doesn't work
end

class Things <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end

class Things <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validate :thing_count_within_limit, :on => :create

  def thing_count_within_limit
    if self.user.things(:reload).count >= 5
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded thing limit")
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit**: updated for Rails 3

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.1 and getting "undefined method `validate_on_create' for #<Class:0x7fd94d9238e8>"

Comment: Great! Please go ahead and accept the answer if it did a good job of addressing your question :)

Comment: I am wondering how would you count only things with a specific attribute value, e.g. thing.status = 'published'?

Comment: This is not concurrent safe

Answer (score 3):

It did not work on Rails 3.2.1. Count always equals to `0`. I have replaced it with `self.user.things.size` and now it works.