# Getting `undefined method` ruby on rails on validation creating new object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863618/rails-3-1-limit-user-created-objects) and trying to add a validate method before object creation. I keep getting `undefined method 'video' for #<Video:0xbe430a0>` I am reading this article here http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/ getting to know how ruby works but cannot figure out why I get this error.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate

If I call new on a ruby object and save it with a validation what do I need to do to the video variable to not get `undefined method`?

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord

  validate :video_count_within_limit, on: :create

  def video_count_within_limit
    if video(:reload).count >= 9
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded video limit of 9 videos")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try replacing `video` with `self`

Comment: If what you're attempting to do is replicate the same structure from the post you're following, then your Video model should also have 

    `belongs_to :some_model`

and then you'd check for the number of videos on that particular models with

    `self.some_model.video(:reload).count` (although the `self` part is not necessary).

The way you're doing it now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I understand that, I was just trying to do it in one model. Is there another way using just the Video model? Thankyou pavan I did try that before with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `video` method actually doesn't exists on your model, and based on post you're following it's actually a reference you should just simple replace `video` with `self`. Something like this: if self.reload.count >= 9 errors.add(:base, "Exceeded video limit of 9 videos") end Let me know if this works for you ! Regards

---

**New Answer :**

On post you're following, they are checking `videos` as association and then checking if its count bigger then 9.

How it works is actually is that the main object which is referenced to the `videos` is not stored to DB but it has `videos` association so you can check length/count of that.

In your case, if you're trying to do that on your main object ( `Video` ) you will get an error that it couldn't be find as it's not persisted but just instantiated as well as your validation method is called before `create`.

This way you're trying to achieve, it's logical only for validating creating some referenced model, which can't be stored has more then 9 videos.

Hope it's clear enough ?

Regards

Comment: Hi. It is giving me error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in VideosController#create Couldn't find Video without an ID` I actually am not sure what that means, I have two videos in database with id: 1 and id: 2?

Comment: But you're using it in #create action so I suppose your video is still not persisted. Seems you're on wrong way, as post you're following actually check videos as references and that's true. You're trying to check `count` on your instantiated object which is wrong !

Comment: I dont understand the difference if it is to a user or to a specific model, shouldnt the count count the amount of records in the db? So before create validate runs and returns the errors?

Comment: Maybe you can just tell what exactly do you want to achieve, it would be much easier to help you ;)

Comment: Yes completely clear. I just wanted to check the count of the videos on the video model before create so that people can not add any more than 9 videos?

Comment: To be clear this is a test app, my 'real' app has a association, but was doing some testing on one model..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149571/discussion-between-zauzaj-and-lee-eather).